# Excel Product Codes like this D745FA.08543.C9999

Tags: excel, xcode, excel-formula, product

For work I need to modify an existing excel column in which the product codes wil be entered. The product codes now look like this: **D745FA08543C9999**

But they need to automatically look like this: **D745FA.08543.C9999**
I need it to have a dot after the first 6 letter/numbers and after the next 5.

I have no idea how i should go about doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write a VBA event-triggered macro that formats the contents using the VBA `Format` function.  Write back with what you have tried either as an answer, or edit your question to show where you have run into problems.  If you want to use just formulas, you can do this using the various string functions (LEFT, MID and/or RIGHT) or the REPLACE function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go like this:

```
=LEFT(A1,6)&"."&MID(A1,7,5)&"."&RIGHT(A1,5)
```

This formula takes the first 6 letters of the text in cell A1, then the two in the middle and then five from the right and puts a period sign between each segment.

If you want to do it directly in the cell, you'll need to use a macro to iterate through the cells and do it in place.

Comment: Great thanks, but how do I apply this to an entire Column. There are 564 Rows that have Product codes, so I don't want to have to modify them on a Cell base but more like; Information entered into column D will automatically have the formula applied to them.

Comment: You could add your conversion macro to the Worksheet_Change event of your worksheet, verify if the entry was made in column D, and then replace the value accordingly.